# Docker log without new line

Tags: docker

I'd like to have a container outputting dots like a progress bar. Like this:

`....... done!`

dots are produced with `echo -n '.'` and done with `echo " done!"`

The problem is that `docker logs` appears to only output whole lines. So all dots will appear at once along with the `done` part.

I tried `stdbuf -o0 echo -n '.'` and `docker run myimage stdbuf -o0 myscript.sh`, but to no luck.

Is there a way to achieve this?